# Eliminating production of collection node for maxOccurs="unbounded" collections with Jackson in java

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

If i have a schema to produce like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="address_listType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="input_location" type="input_locationType"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And i create a Jackson annotated bean like:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "input_location" })
public class AddressListTypeImpl implements AddressListType {

    private List<InputLocationType> m_inputLocationTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("input_location")
    public InputLocationType[] getInputLocationArray() {
        return m_inputLocationTypes.toArray(new InputLocationType[m_inputLocationTypes.size()]);
    }
}
```

When i convert this bean to xml, using:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
return xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(myAddressList);
```

i get:

```
<input_location>
    <input_location x="X:4" multimatchNumber="1000" id="ID:1" latitude="80.2" longitude="44.1" srid="SRID: 5" y="Y:2">
    </input_location>
</input_location>
```

But given the schema i must generate, i don't want the collection to output a node for itself, just one for each of the elements in the collection.

How do i tell jackson not to produce a node for the collection itself?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
```